# Why does this recursive summation function return None?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def recursiveadd(x,sum1):
    if x > 0:
        sum1 += x
        recursiveadd(x-1,sum1)
    else:
        return sum1

print recursiveadd(100,0)
```

Inserting a "print sum1" after the addition shows that sum1 is being increased, so I don't understand why the function returns None. The only thing I can think of is that sum1 is somehow being reset to 0 before being returned, but I have no idea why that would be.

Comment: Trace your code and look what's being returned, emphasis on *returned*.

Comment: Note that tail-recursion can blow up the stack in python.

Comment: @MattFenwick: you can [call it without blowing up the stack](http://ideone.com/IvIyC)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write

```
def recursiveadd(x,sum1):
    if x > 0:
        sum1 += x
        return recursiveadd(x-1,sum1)
    else:
        return sum1

print recursiveadd(100,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [52]: def rec(x, sum = None):
if sum == None:
    sum = 0
if x > 0:
    sum += x
    return rec(x - 1, sum)
else:          
    return sum
```

....:

```
In [53]: rec(100)
Out[53]: 5050
```